# Android - ClassNotFoundException after refactoring

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I've recently refactored class, package and folder names in my app (it's currently called MyApp) using Eclipse's refactor command, and I'm not getting a ClassNotFoundException.  I've made sure there are no more instances of the old name anywhere in the code base.  I've also deleted all the class files in `\bin\classes` and generated Java files in `\gen` (both of which have regenerated, I've checked).  I've also updated the API level from 16 to 17 in an attempt to solve the problem.  Here is the stack trace:

```
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.myapp.MyApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapp.MyApp" on path: /data/app/com.myapp-2.apk
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapp.MyApp" on path: /data/app/com.myapp-2.apk
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:968)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
12-22 17:00:46.690: E/AndroidRuntime(25466):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my Manifest.  I know hardcoding strings is bad style.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:name="MyApp"
        android:label="MyApp"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".Otheractivity"
            android:label="Otheractivity">
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:label="MainMenu">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you have MyApp.java in com.myapp?

Comment: make sure you have `MyApp.java` Application class in `com.myapp` package. if not then remove `android:name="MyApp"` attribute from `Application tag from Manifest

Comment: Sometimes it helps to clean the project in eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:name="MyApp"` in your Manifest means you need to have `MyApp.java`, declaring the class `MyApp` extending `Application` in your `com.myapp` package.

Answer (score 16):

had the same problem, solved it by :

right click your project -> Java build path -> order and export(tab) -> make 'v' on "android private libraries"

tell me if it worked.

Comment: Worked for me. **Note**: you have to allow `android private libraries` for **both** projects.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work at first, but then did a project clean and it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For those who still get this error in Android Studio, I resolved this by deleting .gradle folder from root directory -> clean and build -> run app again.

Answer (score 0):

with the latest version of eclipse/ adt I get this sometimes when I have external libraries included.  Removing them from the build path, and re-adding usually works to fix it.